# Trying to show $A\cap B\trianglelefteq AB$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $A$ is abelian and $A\trianglelefteq G$. Let $B$ be any subgroup of $G$. I'm trying to prove that $A\cap B\trianglelefteq AB$.

If I let $c\in A\cap B$ and let $g\in AB$, I can write $g=ab$ for some $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Then $gcg^{-1}=abc(ab)^{-1}=abcb^{-1}a^{-1}$.

Now I'm stuck. I'm trying to show the above is in $A\cap B$ to establish normality.

Comment: General tip: if you're asked to prove that a property follows from a set of givens, and you find yourself stuck, one place to start is asking "Is there anything given that I haven't used yet?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you want to show that $gcg^{-1}\in A\cap B$. By assumption $c\in A$, as $A$ is normal you have that $gcg^{-1}\in A$.

Moreover, $c\in B$, hence $bcb^{-1}\in B$, it is left to show that $a(bcb^{-1})a^{-1}\in B$, here we use the fact that $A$ is abelian, we have

$$abcb^{-1}a^{-1}=aa^{-1}(abcb^{-1}a^{-1})=a^{-1}(abcb^{-1}a^{-1})a = bcb^{-1}$$ 
Hence, $abcb^{-1}a^{-1}$ is also an element of $B$ and therefore it is an element of $A\cap B$.